# SharePoint User Facing error as Error: Access Denied

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I am having few users for my SharePoint site .And for one of the user have contribution rights to the site but when he tries to access the site he is facing the error as Error: Access Denied .Can any one help me how can I over come from the issue

Comment: Are you trying to access to a page or a list view? Check if the user has the right permission on the element.

Comment: I had checked,And the user is having Contribution rights